# Python проверка программ

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть 2 программы написаны на языке Python, выполняют они одну и тоже задачу только они реализованы по разному. Есть ли способы проверить какая из программ выполняет поставленную задачу лучше (например не загружает память, выполняет за меньшее количество времени) какие используется программы для проверка (извиняюсь сразу если выразился не правильно)? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: вы забыли опубликовать свои программы.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить обе программы по очереди, открыв системный мониторинг. Проверьте сколько ресурсов расходует каждая программа. Так же получите время начала запуска и время конца запуска программы. Это делается так:

```
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.now()
```

вставьте строки

```
x = datetime.datetime.now() # Вначале кода
y = datetime.datetime.now() # В конце кода
```

и в конце выполнения выведите результат:

```
print(x)
print('\n')
print(y)
```

сравните первый показатель со вторым. Это время выполнения программы.
Соответственно - та программа, которая выполнилась быстрее и потребовала меньше ресурсов системы для выполнения - является более практичной для применения.

Comment: выводит ошибку AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

Comment: Проверьте мой ответ.

Comment: попробуйте импорт заменить на from datetime import datetime

Comment: Нет. Все верно. Нужно использовать datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: зачем х и у принтовать отдельно ? y-x ведь выведет время работы

Comment: Всё хорошо, спасибо попробуем